# Javascript loop through and combine dates in object

Tags: javascript, function, date

I need help with something that might be a common problem and something that others would benefit from as well, which is to modify dates in an object and combine them into a chronological list. The overall goal is to create a list which reflects all of the upcoming special dates in a year:

```
1 Jan - Sharpe's Anniversary
2 May - Edward's Birthday
12 Dec - Zero's Anniversary
etc...
```

I began by creating an object to represent this. Then slice out the year so that a comparison won't just arrange them by their order of initial occurrence, but will give an annual basis. Then perform a comparison to arrange the dates in chronological order. Then log out the result with the matching person's identity.

Up to this point I got it to work. However, I do not know how to repeat this and make it DRY. Certainly it would be sloppy to run this for anniversaries, then for birthdays without making some sort of custom function. All my attempts have not ended successfully.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Much thanks to the community here :)

```js
// Sample data

var items = [{
    name: 'Edward',
    anniversary: "2015-01-23",
    birthday: "1988-05-02"
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharpe',
    anniversary: "2017-01-01",
    birthday: "1988-05-10"
  },
  {
    name: 'And',
    anniversary: "2018-05-10",
    birthday: "1988-06-12"
  },
  {
    name: 'The',
    anniversary: "1988-08-11",
    birthday: "1979-03-12"
  },
  {
    name: 'Magnetic',
    anniversary: "2017-01-05",
    birthday: "1956-06-21"
  },
  {
    name: 'Zeros',
    anniversary: "1990-12-12",
    birthday: "1935-07-23"
  }
];

// Slice out the year so that dates are annualized

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].anniversary = items[i].anniversary.slice(5, 10);
};

// Sort dates in chronological order
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.anniversary) - new Date(b.anniversary);
});

// Console.log the dates with their associated name

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].anniversary + " " + items[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the year from a date like "1988-08-11" you get "08-11". If you then parse this with the built-in Date parser, you'll either get an invalid date, or a date for 1 November 0008, when the original date was for 11 August. The parser will see a year and a month, and use 1 for the missing day.

But don't dispair! The ISO 8601 date format can be sorted as a string, so do as you are and sort as strings, not dates, e.g.

```js
// Sample data
var items = [{
    name: 'Edward',
    anniversary: "2015-01-23",
    birthday: "1988-05-02"
  },
  {
    name: 'Sharpe',
    anniversary: "2017-01-01",
    birthday: "1988-05-10"
  },
  {
    name: 'And',
    anniversary: "2018-05-10",
    birthday: "1988-06-12"
  },
  {
    name: 'The',
    anniversary: "1988-08-11",
    birthday: "1979-03-12"
  },
  {
    name: 'Magnetic',
    anniversary: "2017-01-05",
    birthday: "1956-06-21"
  },
  {
    name: 'Zeros',
    anniversary: "1990-12-12",
    birthday: "1935-07-23"
  }
];

// Get the events
var specialDates = items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  acc.push([item.name, item.anniversary.substr(5), 'Anniversary'], [item.name, item.birthday.substr(5), 'Birthday']);
  return acc;
}, []).sort(function (a, b) {  // sort on month
  return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
}).map(function(event) {       // Replace month number with short name
  var months = [,'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  return [event[0], months[+event[1].split('-')[0]] + ' ' + event[1].substr(3), event[2]];
});

// Write result
specialDates.forEach(function(event) {
  console.log(event[1] + ': ' +  event[0] + ' ' + event[2]);
});
```

This could be a bit smarter and get the event name from the original object so that you can add as many event types as you want and not have them hard coded, so an object like:

```
var items = [{
    name: 'Edward',
    events: {
      anniversary: "2015-01-23",
      birthday: "1988-05-02"
    }
  },
  ...
```

Also note that `new Date("2015-01-23")` will treat the string as UTC (timezone offset +00:00), so for hosts west of Greenwich the date might appear to be the day before.

Comment: Rob this is a PERFECT answer. I'm also interested in this smarter version. How would you do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

```
let goal = items
.map( ({ name, anniversary }) => ({ name, 'anniversary': anniversary.slice( 5, 10 ) }) )
.sort( ({ 'anniversary': a }, { 'anniversary': b }) => {
    if( a > b ) return 1;
    if( a < b ) return -1;
    return 0;
}
.map( ({ name, anniversary }) => anniversary + ' ' + name );

goal.forEach( item => { console.log( item ); });
```